# Делать что-то украдкой

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Слово "украдкой" родственно слову "украсть" или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Украдкой - скрытно, тайком, незаметно для других. Точно так же обычно и крадут. Значит,  слова "украдкой" и "украсть" что-то роднит.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее от глагола "красться", но связь с "красть" несомненна